# Pointer declaration with a specific address

Tags: c, pointers

Consider this:

```
(volatile unsigned long *) 0x4000703C
```

Does this statement mean we declare a pointer **to** the address `0x4000703C`? And:

```
#define STEPPER (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x4000703C))

void Step(void){
  STEPPER = 10;
  STEPPER = 9;
  STEPPER = 5;
  STEPPER = 6;
}
```

`STEPPER` is the deference of the pointer at the address `0x4000703C`, and we are writing directly to `0x4000703C`. Is it correct?

Comment: No and yes. The first is not a declaration, it's an expression that yields a pointer to an `unsigned long` and which points to a specific address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this statement mean we declare a pointer to the address

No, a declaration includes an *identifier*, in this case a variable name. You have an operation which casts an integer to a pointer type, pointing at `0x4000703C`. Nothing was declared.

> STEPPER is the deference of the pointer at the address 0x4000703C, and we are writing directly to 0x4000703C. Is it correct?

Yes. What kind of memory there is at `0x4000703C` is of course completely system-specific.

Comment: Yes, in this case `0x4000703C` is address of an I/O port. Thanks for confirming, as I am still studying.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing directly to that address in virtual memory, yes.

Comment: How do you know that there is virtual memory without the OP specifying what system this runs on? Not every computer is a PC.

Answer (score 0):

This technique is used widely on embedded system programming to define hardware registers.

update:

Just in case, for people that might want to know more about using this technique in embedded system field:

- [Placing C variables at specific addresses to access memory-mapped peripherals](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3750.html) from ARM.
- [Methods of Hardware Access in C++](http://www.strongenging.com/papers/HardwareAccessinC.pdf)

Comment: I dont' see why downvote. When you write low-level firmware, this technique is indeed widely used to define hardware peripheral.

Comment: Probably because this should be posted as a comment, not an answer. You don't answer either of the two questions asked.